# How to include Jquery plugin in RequireJS and BackboneJS

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I want to use the image Lazyload.js plugin in my BackboneJS/RequireJS app but dont know how to do this. Could anyone give a hint? This is the plugin I want to use [lazyload plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)

I already downloaded it and defined it in my config.js:

```
require.config({

 paths: {   
      jquery: '../lib/jquery-2.0.3.min',
      underscore: '../lib/lodash-2.2.1.min',
      backbone: '../lib/backbone-1.0.0.min',     
     lazyload: '../lib/jquery.lazyload.min'
 },

 shim: {backbone, handlebars etc...}

});
```

I've read that I have to apply some:

```
define(["jquery"], 
   function($){
   ...
});
```

at the end of the plugin-code?

Answer (score 0):

I am copying my file.. from this you can get decent idea how to incude jquery plugins/files in backbone. Write main.js like this. i think your missing deps.

```
require.config({
      baseURL: 'scripts',
      paths: {
        jquery: "../../lib/js/zepto/zepto",
        Underscore: "../../lib/js/underscore-amd/underscore",
        Backbone: "../../lib/js/backbone-amd/backbone",
        text: "../../lib/js/requirejs-text/text",
        ChromeExtension: "../chrome-extension",
        Config: "../config",
        Constants: "../constants",
        NotificationService: "notification-service",
        SocketIO: "../../lib/js/socket.io-client/socket.io",
        deffered: "../../lib/js/simply-deffered/deferred",
        PusherClient: "../../lib/js/pusher/pusher.min"
      },
      shim: {
        Constants: {
          deps: ['Config']
        },
        jquery: {
          deps: [],
          exports: '$',
          init: function() {
            return window.jQuery = $;
          }
        },
        Backbone: {
          deps: ['jquery', 'Underscore'],
          exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        Underscore: {
          exports: '_'
        },
        NotificationService: {
          deps: ['SocketIO', 'Backbone']
        },
        deffered: {
          deps: ['jquery'],
          exports: 'Deffered'
        },
        PusherClient: {
          deps: [],
          exports: 'PusherClient'
        }
      }
    });
```